# trigger a pop-up window in a function angular

Tags: angular

I'm thinking about how to trigger a pop-up window in an existing function. What I currently have is like:

```
foo() {
    // code
}
```

I'm going to show a pop-up window once the function foo is executed. My current idea is to use a boolean variable flag in the foo function and correspondingly use *ngif in the html.

```
*ngIf "flag" // If flag==true then shows the pop-up window, otherwise doesn't show.
```

Any optimized suggestions would be great!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use ngx-bootstrap it give a lot of features like modals

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals